# Act differentely according to a given type in a generic function

Tags: typescript, generics

```
type Foo = number | string

function f<Type extends Foo>(v: Type[]) {
  // can I act here in function of Type?
  // pseudo-code: if (Type == number) {} else if (Type == string) {}
}

f<number>([1, 2]);
```

I'm a typescript beginner so this question is probably very naive

Comment: The answer to the question as asked is "no"; the `Type` type parameter is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) from the JavaScript that actually runs; it will look like `function f(v) {}` and the call will be `f([1, 2])`; there's no `Type` and no `number`.  Is there something specific you want to do depending on whether you pass in an array of strings or an array of numbers?

Comment: My real case is more complicated than that but yes, I have many types that are slightly different and form an union type and `f` must accept all those types (hence the generics system) and for certain of them, add a slightly different behavior. Maybe I'll have to redondate the "information" of the given type with a string variable?